# Opentelemetry set up for Angular Project- Export to Zipkin Problem

Tags: angular, zipkin, open-telemetry

I have a hello-world Angular project that I'm trying to set up opentelemetry on it. There is no back end and I just want to see the traces for the frontend. I followed the instruction provided by the following library but I don't get the traces on Zipkin:
[opentelemetry-angular-interceptor](https://github.com/jufab/opentelemetry-angular-interceptor)

There is no specific error when I run ng serve, I just can't see the traces.

This is what I've done on this project:

Environment.ts file:

```
import { DiagLogLevel } from '@opentelemetry/api';
import {
  OpenTelemetryConfig
} from '@jufab/opentelemetry-angular-interceptor';

interface IEnvironment {
  production: boolean;
  urlTest: string;
  openTelemetryConfig: OpenTelemetryConfig;
}

// Example to configure the angular-interceptor library
export const environment: IEnvironment = {
  production: false,
  urlTest: 'http://localhost:4200',
  openTelemetryConfig: {
    commonConfig: {
      console: true, // Display trace on console
      production: true, // Send Trace with BatchSpanProcessor (true) or SimpleSpanProcessor (false)
      serviceName: 'instrumentation-example', // Service name send in trace
      probabilitySampler: '1', // 75% sampling
      logLevel: DiagLogLevel.ALL //ALL Log, DiagLogLevel is an Enum from @opentelemetry/api
    },
    zipkinConfig: {
      url: 'http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans'
    },
    b3PropagatorConfig: {
      multiHeader: '0' //Value : 'O' (single), '1' (multi)
    },
    instrumentationConfig: {
      xmlHttpRequest: true,
      fetch: true,
      documentLoad: true,
    }
  }
};
```

app.module.ts file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {
  ZipkinExporterModule,
  CompositePropagatorModule,
  OtelWebTracerModule,
} from '@jufab/opentelemetry-angular-interceptor';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ZipkinExporterModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    //Insert propagator module
    CompositePropagatorModule,
    OtelWebTracerModule.forRoot(environment.openTelemetryConfig),
    
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Added configuration to environment.ts file and imported all necessary modules including ZipkinExporterModule to app.module.ts but can't see the traces on Zipkin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out! I just added

```
"<otel-instrumentation></otel-instrumentation>"
```

to the component! and It's working now.